# How can I send command line inputs during a pipeline run?

Tags: input, command-line, gitlab, pipeline

I'm using a binary in a Gitlab pipeline.
This binary expects an input during the run which I cannot provide so my pipeline run fails.

On my local setup, everything is working just fine.
$HOME/bin/binary-name ENTER
*binary starts its things*
*Please input XYZ to confirm your action*
XYZ ENTER
*done*

I tried adding an 'echo "xyz"' to my .gitlab-ci.yml but it's not working since the earlier process (which was starting the binary) doesn't finish and fails.

Is there any way to provide that input?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I exactly understand what you are trying to do. A minimal example of what you currently have would be really helpful to understand your setting.

But it seems that you want to pass input to the standard input of the program that is executed. If you are running linux you are probably looking for the pipe `|` operator. This is commonly used e.g. for docker login like

```yaml
...
job1:
  script:
    - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | buildah login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" --password-stdin $CI_REGISTRY
```

If the input is much longer, instead of `echo` you could consider saving the information in a file and use `cat`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
It's hard to explain without showing code. But I cannot do that due to company restrictions.

I'm running a gitlab pipeline. The first command in my "script" section is executing a binary.
During the execution, this binary requires a confirmation command line input. It is a failsafe so the user doesn't accidentally deletes something.
You start the binary - wait a few seconds - and then there is a prompt like with yum install "Do you really want to install?". Which you need to confirm by typing "yes".
And I need to provide that input during the pipeline run.